# Best way to get the connected network domain name in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to find out whether the local Windows system is connected to a network domain (instead of a workgroup) and if so, read the domain's name.

I found these Windows API functions to achieve this:

```
  GetEnvironmentVariable('USERDNSDOMAIN')
  NetGetJoinInformation
  NetServerGetInfo
  NetWkstaGetInfo
  LookupAccountSid
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages between them? (faster, more reliable, more accurate, ...)

Which one would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1):

`LookupAccountSid` is more focused on searching for sid, `NetServerGetInfo` is focused on retrieving server information.
So neither of these applies to you.

The domain name gets from `NetGetJoinInformation` and `NetWkstaGetInfo` correspond to `USERDOMAIN` instead of `USERDNSDOMAIN`, Depending on the domain name you want.

`GetEnvironmentVariable` is the function that just get the value of a variable and can be modified by `SetEnvironmentVariable` at any time (Even though we usually don't do this), so I don't recommend it.

> No special group membership is required to successfully execute the
>   [`NetGetJoinInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netgetjoininformation) function.

And it is more pure than `NetWkstaGetInfo`(according to your requirement)

Answer (score 1):

most direct and efficient here - call [`LsaQueryInformationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaqueryinformationpolicy) with *PolicyDnsDomainInformation*. on output you got filled [`POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lsalookup/ns-lsalookup-policy_dns_domain_info) structure. here will be name and DNS name of the primary domain. and also it *SID*

> If the computer associated with the Policy object is not a member of a
>   domain, all structure members except Name are NULL or zero.

```
#include <Ntsecapi.h>

NTSTATUS PrintDomainName()
{
    LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle;

    static LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa) };

    NTSTATUS status = LsaOpenPolicy(0, &oa, POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION, &PolicyHandle);

    if (LSA_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        PPOLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO ppddi;

        if (LSA_SUCCESS(status = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(PolicyHandle, PolicyDnsDomainInformation, (void**)&ppddi)))
        {
            if (ppddi->Sid)
            {
                DbgPrint("DnsDomainName: %wZ\n", &ppddi->DnsDomainName);
            }
            else
            {
                DbgPrint("%wZ: not a member of a domain\n", &ppddi->Name);
            }

            LsaFreeMemory(ppddi);

        }

        LsaClose(PolicyHandle);
    }

    return status;
}
```

the `NetGetJoinInformation` internally do the same - query *PolicyDnsDomainInformation*, but do this not in your but in remote process (*svchost.exe -k networkservice -p -s LanmanWorkstation* - *LanmanWorkstation* service) and many additional calls do. so it less efficient, but and less source code for call this api

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation (I think some words got mixed up there...). Could you please check? Also, LsaQueryInformationPolicy requires loading Advapi32.dll first. Doesn't this make it slower than using a method from a dll that is already loaded by default?

Comment: @CodeX - no, direct call to `LsaOpenPolicy` + `LsaQueryInformationPolicy` + `LsaFreeMemory` + `LsaClose` will be much faster compare `NetGetJoinInformation` call - because all this anyway called in this path + additional remote call + many other additional calls

Comment: @CodeX - and by default loaded only ntdll.dll, *NetGetJoinInformation* for example require load *Wkscli.dll* and all it dependencies.. which will be much more compare *advapi32.dll*. however despite use Lsa api more efficient - in single call you not view big difference. but more dlls (potential) will be again in Net case